# How to reset the properties of anaconda prompt shortcut?

Tags: python, anaconda

[image]

I am very new to python and I just downloaded anaconda a few days ago.

As you can see from the image, I think I changed 'Target' path accidently but I don't know how to reset it. As a result, I cannot open anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 3):

My file path looks like this

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
```

Maybe this will help on refinding your path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe %LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py %LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3 "%LOCALAPPDATA%/Continuum/Anaconda3/python.exe" "%LOCALAPPDATA%/Continuum/Anaconda3/Scripts/jupyter-notebook-script.py`

Comment: Hi! Please format your code by adding backticks right before and right after your code, like so: \`this_is_code()\` will result in `this_is_code()` which is more readable. Thanks :)